# Hop_Size meaning in aubio

Tags: c, audio, aubio

I'm trying to use the aubio(https://aubio.org) library for pitch detection. I'm trying to use the API for C and one of the parameters of the `new_aubio_pitch` function is `hop_size`. What does `hop_size` mean and how do you choose one?

Comment: First result from [Google search](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Choice_Hop_Size.html)

Comment: I.e. `hop_size` tells how many samples it can jump forward after one frame of FFT analysis. 1 is the best, any larger is a trade-off between quality and speed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hop size should refer to the number of samples in between successive frames. For signal analysis Hop Size should be less than the frame size, so that frames overlap.

In the diagram below

- Hop size would be *`Q`*
- frame size would be *`K`*
- all in relation to a signal *`s(n)`*

[image: Illustration of DSP windowing and frame overlap]

If your follow up question is 'why would you do that?', then there is a good answer to be found at this topic here:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36509/why-is-each-window-frame-overlapping